# Use drawable animation as large icon in notification android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, animation, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin Android with C#.

In the notification builder I can set a large icon like this:

[image: Small Icon & Large Icon]
(Not mine picture)

```
            NotificationCompat.Builder notbuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "0");
            notbuilder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.miconNotify);
            notbuilder.SetColor(GetColor(Resource.Color.notifyColor));
            notbuilder.SetContentText("DownloadText");
            notbuilder.SetContentTitle("DownloadTitle");
            notbuilder.SetLargeIcon(WHAT_COMES_HERE); //<----------- (needs a Bitmap)
```

Is it possible to animate the large icon somehow (like the Google Play Store while downloads does)? I've tried to use a animation list xml but I found no way to start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a realy simple solution:

```
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "0");
            builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.miconNotify);
            builder.SetColor(GetColor(Resource.Color.notifyColor));
            builder.SetContentText("Download1");
            builder.SetContentTitle("DownloadTitle");
            builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.NotifyAnim0));

            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            manager.Notify(0, builder.Build()); //Notify for the first time

            bool DownloadFinished = false;

            Task TaskA = new Task(() => 
            {
                while (!DownloadFinished)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.NotifyAnim0)); //Pic 1
                    manager.Notify(0, builder.Build());
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.NotifyAnim1)); //Pic 2
                    manager.Notify(0, builder.Build());
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.NotifyAnim2)); //Pic 3
                    manager.Notify(0, builder.Build());
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.NotifyAnim3)); // Pic 4
                    manager.Notify(0, builder.Build());
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.NotifyAnim4)); //Pic 5
                    manager.Notify(0, builder.Build());
                }
            });
            TaskA.Start();
```

Be sure you are using `NotificationCompat.Builder`!
The task runs parallel and the app works just normal.
To stop the animation just set `DownloadFinished` to `true`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing, please accpet your answer after two days.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share a gif about your needs?

If you want to change the icon like a GIF result, I cannot found a way to achieve it.

However, I you want to add a progress bar like Google Play Store while downloads, it could be achieved by `RemoteView` like this running gif.

[image]

I used `RemoteView` for `Notification`

```
  RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.PackageName, Resource.Layout.layout_nitification);

            views.SetProgressBar(Resource.Id.progressBar1,100,1,false);

              // Create the PendingIntent with the back stack:            
              var resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int) PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
         
            // Build the notification:
            var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .SetContent(views)
                          .SetAutoCancel(true) // Dismiss the notification from the notification area when the user clicks on it
                          .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent) // Start up this activity when the user clicks the intent.
                          .SetContentTitle("Button Clicked") // Set the title
                          .SetNumber(count) // Display the count in the Content Info
                        
                          .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
                          .SetContentText($"The button has been clicked {count} times."); // the message to display.
```

Here is code about `layout_nitification.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp">
    <ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"/>
  
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a notification"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If above answer is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: [link](https://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Google-Play-Store-Missing-Update-Notification-GIF.gif) -> Google seems to use the small icon, but i try to use the large one. And I got my own animated gif if that helps.

Comment: The large icon use Bitmap to set it, We cannot set the `Bitmap` to animate